# Batch - Comparing two txt files

Tags: windows, batch-file, text, comparison

I have some difficulties comparing two txt files with batch.
I used the "findstr" function with many option matchings but none works (for example FINDSTR /I /V /B /G:file1.txt file2.txt).
I have a first txt file as following:

File1.txt

```
Object 1
Argument 50
Object 2
Argument 10
Object 3
Argument 10
Object 4
Argument 10
```

The second file has the same beginning as the first one:

File2.txt

```
Object 1
Argument 50
Object 2
Argument 10
Object 3
Argument 10
Object 4
Argument 10
Object 5
Argument 10
Object 6
Argument 50
Object 7
Argument 10
Object 8
Argument 10
```

The purpose of this comparaison is to separate the parts which are repeated (on the same lines only) in the second file. The results have to be as following:

File1.txt (unchanged)

```
Object 1    
Argument 50        
Object 2
Argument 10
Object 3
Argument 10
Object 4
Argument 10
```

and

File2.txt

```
Object 5
Argument 10
Object 6
Argument 50
Object 7
Argument 10
Object 8
Argument 10
```

A For loop may perhaps be usefull...
Thanks a lot for your precious help!

Comment: Linux? Windows? What did you try to do, which command and options did you try?

Comment: On windows. I need to integrate this comparison in a batch file.
I tried this function; FINDSTR /I /V /B /G:file1.txt file2.txt

Comment: I recommend you add that to your question. You need to show what you tried. Then people can help better.

Comment: Why reinvent the wheel? There's plenty of diff tools available; kdiff, beyondcompare, to only name a few

Comment: You need to be more specific as to how you want to compare the files and/or what constraints exist on the starting data. I've edited your question with questions of my own that do not fit within a comment.

Comment: @dbenham, the file2 is necessary the continuation of file1, I can't have characters in file2 that aren't in file1.

Comment: So you want all content from File2 from the point at which it begins to differ from File1?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code below keep lines from File2.txt from the first line that differ vs. File1.txt on:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

rem Redirect the *larger* file as input
< File2.txt (

   rem Merge it with lines from shorter file
   for /F "delims=" %%a in (file1.txt) do (

      rem Read the next line from File2
      set /P "line="

      rem If it is different than next line from File1...
      if "!line!" neq "%%a" (

         rem Show this line (the first different one)
         echo !line!
         rem Show the rest of lines from File2
         findstr "^"
         rem And terminate
         goto break

      )
   )

   rem If all lines in File1 were equal to File2, show the rest of File2
   findstr "^"

) > File2_new.txt

:break
move /Y File2_new.txt File2.txt
```

Answer (score 2):

If the comparision between the two files is necessary

```dos
@echo off
    setlocal enableextensions disabledelayedexpansion

    set "file1=.\file1.txt"
    set "file2=.\file2.txt"

    rem If it is necessary to COMPARE the same lines of the two files
    for %%t in ("%temp%\%~nx0.%random%%random%.tmp") do (
        findstr /n "^" "%file2%" > "%%~ft.2"
        findstr /n "^" "%file1%" > "%%~ft.1"
        findstr /v /l /b /g:"%%~ft.1" "%%~ft.2" > "%%~ft"
        (for /f "usebackq tokens=* delims=0123456789" %%a in ("%%~ft") do (
            set "line=%%a"
            setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
            echo(!line:~1!
            endlocal
        )) > "%file2%.new"
        del /q "%%~ft*"
    )
    type "%file2%.new"
```

Or, if file2 is always file1 plus more lines

```dos
@echo off
    setlocal enableextensions disabledelayedexpansion

    set "file1=.\file1.txt"
    set "file2=.\file2.txt"

    rem If the only need is to skip the start of the second file 
    rem AND it has less than 65535 lines
    for /f %%a in ('find /v /c "" ^< "%file1%"') do set "nLines=%%a"
    more +%nLines% < "%file2%" > "%file2%.new"
    type "%file2%.new"
```

Comment: Thank you MC ND! The script works pretty well! The only thing that doesn't work perfectly is that the generated "file2" has the first line skipped :)

Comment: @Elhendriks, not sure if it is the first code or the second (now separated for clarity) that generates the file with the missing line. The only thing I can see is in the second case if the first file includes blank lines that are counted and excluded from the second. Can you give more information?